# Determining logic based on a subset of data

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
data = {'Account': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
        'Customer': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1],
        'Key': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Account Customer    Key
0   1          1         1
1   1          2         0
2   1          3         1
3   2          2         0
4   2          4         1
5   3          5         1
6   4          6         1
7   4          1         1
```

I need to add two levels of logic:

1. mark whether all clients in a given account have the "Key" column = 1. If so, we set the value 1 to all clients in a specific account.
2. carry out the marking according to the logic from point 1 and additionally exclude clients who were included in at least one account from the first level of aggregation by accounts (e.g. client no. 1 is included in account 4 because it appears in account 1 where not all clients have Key = 1)

I did it with a SQL approach

1st logic level:

```
#Min key value grouped by account
df_grouped = df.groupby(by = ['Account'])['Key'].min().to_frame().reset_index()
df_grouped.rename(columns = {'Key' : 'LVL_AGGR_1'}, inplace = True)
df_grouped

#SQL Left join
df_1 = df.merge(df_grouped, left_on = 'Account', right_on = 'Account', how = 'left')
df_1
```

2nd logic level:

```
df_grouped_1 = df_1.groupby(by = ['Customer'])['LVL_AGGR_1'].min().to_frame().reset_index()
df_grouped_1.rename(columns = {'LVL_AGGR_1' : 'LVL_AGGR_2'}
                        , inplace = True)
df_grouped_1


df_final = df_final.merge(df_grouped_1, left_on = 'Customer', right_on = 'Customer', how = 'left')
df_final
```

I would like to know if there is any other way to do it, using a more Python programming approach than purely SQL logic

Comment: That's not "an SQL approach".  SQL and pandas both happen to implement grouping and merging, which are exactly the operations you need here.  This is how you do it.

Comment: I don't understand #1. If all the clients in an account have value 1 for an account, why do you need to set them to 1? They're already set to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `min` by [`groupby_transform('min')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to broadcast the `min` value to all clients of the same account. In this case, Pandas use the index to align rows:

```
# 1st logic level
df['LVL_AGGR_1'] = df.groupby('Account')['Key'].transform('min')

# 2nd logic level
df['LVL_AGGR_2'] = df.groupby('Customer')['LVL_AGGR_1'].transform('min')
```

With `lambda` evaluation, you can use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```py
df = df.assign(
    LVL_AGGR_1=lambda x: x.groupby('Account')['Key'].transform('min'),
    LVL_AGGR_2=lambda x: x.groupby('Customer')['LVL_AGGR_1'].transform('min')
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Account  Customer  Key  LVL_AGGR_1  LVL_AGGR_2
0        1         1    1           0           0
1        1         2    0           0           0
2        1         3    1           0           0
3        2         2    0           0           0
4        2         4    1           0           0
5        3         5    1           1           1
6        4         6    1           1           1
7        4         1    1           1           0
```